# how to stop the movement of an object

Tags: javascript

Here's what I have:

```html
      <div class="Null"></div>
      <script>
          document.querySelector("body").addEventListener('mousemove', Null);
          function Null(){
         var Null = document.querySelectorAll(".Null");
          Null.forEach(function (Null) {
          let x = (Null.getBoundingClientRect().left) + (Null.clientWidth / 2);
         let y = (Null.getBoundingClientRect().top) + (Null.clientHeight / 2);
         let radian = Math.atan2(event.pageX - x,event.pageY - y);
          let rot = (radian * (180 / Math.PI) * -1) + 270;
         Null.style.transform = "rotate("+ rot +"deg)";
         })
        }

</script>
<style>
 /*Da EyE!?*/
  .Null {
  pointer-events: none;
  position: fixed;
  height: 0px;
  width: 0px;
  padding: 120px;
  background: ;
  margin: auto;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 10px solid rgb(0, 0, 0, 0.21);
  border-bottom-color: transparent;
  border-top-color: transparent;
  border-right-color: transparent;
  }
  .Null:before {
  content: "";
  position: fixed;
  left: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  border: 10px solid rgb(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  border-bottom-color: transparent;
  border-top-color: transparent;
 border-right-color: transparent;
  border-radius: 50%;
 }
</style>
```

I would like the semi-circle to stop following the cursor when "x" is clicked (On Keyboard), and when "x" is click again it will follow the cursor again, also I would like it to stop in the same position as when u hit "x", I have tried this:

```html
      <div class="Null"></div>
      <script>
      document.querySelector("body").addEventListener('mousemove', Null);

      function Null() {
      var Null = document.querySelectorAll(".Null");
      Null.forEach(function(Null) {
      let x = (Null.getBoundingClientRect().left) + (Null.clientWidth / 2);
      let y = (Null.getBoundingClientRect().top) + (Null.clientHeight / 2);
      let radian = Math.atan2(event.pageX - x, event.pageY - y);
      let rot = (radian * (180 / Math.PI) * -1) + 270;
      Null.style.transform = "rotate(" + rot + "deg)";
      })
    }
    // TankOn 1st E click
    var TankOn = true;
      //TankOff Next
    function toggleTank() {
    TankOn ? Tank0n() : TankOff();
    TankOn = !TankOn;
    }

   function Tank0n() {
     var Null = "No"
    }

    function TankOff() {
     var Null = document.querySelectorAll(".Null");
    }
   </script>
   <style>
    /*Da EyE!?*/
  
    .Null {
    pointer-events: none;
    position: fixed;
    height: 0px;
    width: 0px;
    padding: 120px;
    background: ;
    margin: auto;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: 10px solid rgb(0, 0, 0, 0.21);
    border-bottom-color: transparent;
    border-top-color: transparent;
    border-right-color: transparent;
    }
  
    .Null:before {
    content: "";
    position: fixed;
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
    border: 10px solid rgb(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    border-bottom-color: transparent;
    border-top-color: transparent;
    border-right-color: transparent;
    border-radius: 50%;
    }
    </style>
```

I did to try and "end" the function, but that did not work, any ideas?
(it looks like the semi-circle is not following the cursor in Stack Overflow, example): https://matrixmod.glitch.me/test.html

Comment: What do you mean by following the cursor when "x" is pressed? I don't see an "x" by running your code

Comment: i mean the semi- semi-circle will follow your cursor until key down of "x" key.

Comment: The semi-circle is not following the cursor because you can't access the body from the snippet. (To make it work here you need to add a new div as a parent of your existing one and add the listener there, you can check my answer bellow)

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you don't have code detecting the key input and also you're not using your variable `TankOn` inside your `Null` function.

I added a function that detects a keypress and you can then validate if it was an "x"

```
document.addEventListener("keypress", function(e) {
  e = e || window.event;
  if (e.key === 'x' || e.keyCode === 120) {
    toggleTank();
  }
})
```

After that I added a validation in the top of your method `Null` to see if the value of `TankOn` was false I would stop running the function.

```
function Null() {
  if (!TankOn) {
    return;
  }
...
```

And I removed some other methods that you had to clean up the code a little bit, you can check a working example here: *(click on the output screen first so it detects your keypress)*

```js
document.querySelector('.body').addEventListener('mousemove', Null);

function Null() {
  if (!TankOn) {
    return;
  }
  var Null = document.querySelectorAll('.Null');
  Null.forEach(function(Null) {
    let x = Null.getBoundingClientRect().left + Null.clientWidth / 2;
    let y = Null.getBoundingClientRect().top + Null.clientHeight / 2;
    let radian = Math.atan2(event.pageX - x, event.pageY - y);
    let rot = radian * (180 / Math.PI) * -1 + 270;
    Null.style.transform = 'rotate(' + rot + 'deg)';
  });
}

var TankOn = true;

function toggleTank() {
  TankOn = !TankOn;
}

document.addEventListener("keypress", function(e) {
  e = e || window.event;
  if (e.key === 'x' || e.keyCode === 120) {
    toggleTank();
  }
})
```

```css
.body {
  height: 100vh;
}

.Null {
  pointer-events: none;
  position: fixed;
  height: 0px;
  width: 0px;
  padding: 120px;
  background: red;
  margin: auto;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 10px solid rgb(0, 0, 0, 0.21);
  border-bottom-color: transparent;
  border-top-color: transparent;
  border-right-color: transparent;
}

.Null:before {
  content: '';
  position: fixed;
  left: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  border: 10px solid rgb(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  border-bottom-color: transparent;
  border-top-color: transparent;
  border-right-color: transparent;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="body">
  <div class="Null"></div>
</div>
```

Also I recommend you use different names for your functions, variables, and classes so it's easier to understand, and avoid using reserved names with different capitalization to avoid confusions.

Comment: yes, i planed to change the name the switch was copy from another peace of my code for testing.